# Working with Arrays within Arrays in React Native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-redux

I am receiving this type of array from an API (JSON):

```
 {
    "api": {
        "results": 13,
        "players": [
            {
                "player_id": 79308,
                "player_name": "Felipe Ponce Ramírez",
                "firstname": "Felipe",
                "lastname": "Ponce Ramírez",
                "number": null,
                "position": "Midfielder",
                "age": 32,
                "birth_date": "29/03/1988",
                "birth_place": "Ciudad Lerdo",
                "birth_country": "Mexico",
                "nationality": "Mexico",
                "height": "177 cm",
                "weight": "67 kg",
                "injured": null,
                "rating": null,
                "team_id": 4299,
                "team_name": "Alianza",
                "league_id": 2979,
                "league": "Primera Division",
                "season": "2020-2021",
                "captain": 0,
                "shots": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "on": 0
                },
                "goals": {
                    "total": 5,
                    "conceded": 0,
                    "assists": 0,
                    "saves": 0
                },
                "passes": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "key": 0,
                    "accuracy": 0
                },
                "tackles": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "blocks": 0,
                    "interceptions": 0
                },
                "duels": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "won": 0
                },
                "dribbles": {
                    "attempts": 0,
                    "success": 0
                },
                "fouls": {
                    "drawn": 0,
                    "committed": 0
                },
                "cards": {
                    "yellow": 2,
                    "yellowred": 0,
                    "red": 0
                },
                "penalty": {
                    "won": 0,
                    "commited": 0,
                    "success": 0,
                    "missed": 0,
                    "saved": 0
                },
                "games": {
                    "appearences": 7,
                    "minutes_played": 260,
                    "lineups": 3
                },
                "substitutes": {
                    "in": 4,
                    "out": 3,
                    "bench": 0
                }
            }
    // From here on there are 4 objects like this (there are 1 object for the last 5 seasons
           }
        ]
    }
}
```

So I want to extract into 3 Arrays the objects:

```
"goals": {
                    "total": 5,
                    "conceded": 0,
                    "assists": 0,
                    "saves": 0
                },
"cards": {
                    "yellow": 2,
                    "yellowred": 0,
                    "red": 0
                },
"games": {
                    "appearences": 7,
                    "minutes_played": 260,
                    "lineups": 3
                },
```

I have this code to receive the data in my Action File (that feeds my Reducer):

```
import Jugador from '../../models/jugador';
import ResultadoEstadistica from '../../models/estadistica/resultadoEstadistica';
import PlayerEstadistica from '../../models/estadistica/playerEstatisticData';
import Cards from '../../models/estadistica/cards';
import Games from '../../models/estadistica/games';
import Goals from '../../models/estadistica/goals';

export const SET_JUGADORES = 'SET_JUGADORES';
export const SET_ESTADISTICA = 'SET_ESTADISTICA';

export const fetchJugadores = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        //any async code here!!!
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://alianzafc2021-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/jugadores.json'
            );

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Algo salio Mal!');
            }

            const resData = await response.json();
            const loadedJugadores = [];

            for (const key in resData) {
                loadedJugadores.push(
                    new Jugador(
                        key,
                        resData[key].altura,
                        resData[key].apellido,
                        resData[key].edad,
                        resData[key].fecha_nacimiento,
                        resData[key].iso_code,
                        resData[key].imagen,
                        resData[key].lugar_nacimiento,
                        resData[key].nacionalidad,
                        resData[key].nombre_completo,
                        resData[key].nombre_corto,
                        resData[key].nombres,
                        resData[key].numero,
                        resData[key].pais,
                        resData[key].peso,
                        resData[key].player_id,
                        resData[key].posicion
                    )
                );
            }

            dispatch({ type: SET_JUGADORES, players: loadedJugadores });
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    };
}

export const fetchEstadistica = player_id => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        //any async code here!!!
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                `https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/players/player/${player_id}`,
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'x-rapidapi-key': 'My API KEY',
                        'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
                        'useQueryString': 'true'
                    }
                }
            );

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Algo salio Mal!');
            }

            const resData = await response.json();
            const loadesApiResult = [];

            
            console.log('***Impresion desde la accion***');
            console.log(resData);
            console.log('***Fin de Impresion***');

            //Arrays de la Estadistica del Jugador
            const loadedEstadistica = [];
            const loadedCards = [];
            const loadedGoals = [];
            const loadedGames = [];

            for (const key in resData) {
                loadesApiResult.push(
                    new ResultadoEstadistica(
                        resData[key].results,
                        resData[key].players
                    )
                );
            }

            const apiData = loadesApiResult.players;

            for (const key in apiData) {
                loadedEstadistica.push(
                    new PlayerEstadistica(
                        apiData[key].player_id,
                        apiData[key].player_name,
                        apiData[key].firstname,
                        apiData[key].lastname,
                        apiData[key].number,
                        apiData[key].position,
                        apiData[key].age,
                        apiData[key].birth_date,
                        apiData[key].birth_place,
                        apiData[key].birth_country,
                        apiData[key].nationality,
                        apiData[key].height,
                        apiData[key].weight,
                        apiData[key].injured,
                        apiData[key].rating,
                        apiData[key].team_id,
                        apiData[key].team_name,
                        apiData[key].league_id,
                        apiData[key].league,
                        apiData[key].season,
                        apiData[key].captain,
                        apiData[key].shots,
                        apiData[key].goals,
                        apiData[key].passes,
                        apiData[key].duels,
                        apiData[key].dribbles,
                        apiData[key].fouls,
                        apiData[key].cards,
                        apiData[key].penalty,
                        apiData[key].games,
                        apiData[key].substitutes,
                    )
                );
            }

            const playerDataGames = loadedEstadistica.games;

            for (const key in playerDataGames) {
                loadedGames.push(
                    new Games(
                        playerDataGames[key].apperences,
                        playerDataGames[key].minutes_played,
                        playerDataGames[key].lineups
                    )
                );
            };

            const playerDataGoals = loadedEstadistica.goals;

            for (const key in playerDataGoals) {
                loadedGoals.push(
                    new Goals(
                        playerDataGoals[key].total,
                        playerDataGoals[key].conceded,
                        playerDataGoals[key].assists,
                        playerDataGoals[key].saves
                    )
                );
            };

            const playerDataCards = loadedEstadistica.cards;

            for (const key in playerDataCards) {
                loadedCards.push(
                    new Cards(
                        playerDataCards[key].yellow,
                        playerDataCards[key].yellowred,
                        playerDataCards[key].red
                    )
                );
            };

            dispatch({ type: SET_ESTADISTICA, estadistica: loadesApiResult, goles: loadedGoals, juegos: loadedGames, tarjetas: loadedCards });
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    };
};
```

*When I do a Console Log of ResDATA I get the original Response, any idea on how I can put the **GOALS, CARDS and GAMES Sub Arrays** of the First Object into 3 separate Arrays which I will be forwarding to the Reducer.*

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do you mean like this?**

```
result =  [
  {
    "total": 5,
    "conceded": 0,
    "assists": 0,
    "saves": 0
  },
  {
    "yellow": 2,
    "yellowred": 0,
    "red": 0
  },
  {
    "appearences": 7,
    "minutes_played": 260,
    "lineups": 3
  }
]
```

```js
const json = {
    "api": {
        "results": 13,
        "players": [
            {
                "player_id": 79308,
                "player_name": "Felipe Ponce Ramírez",
                "firstname": "Felipe",
                "lastname": "Ponce Ramírez",
                "number": null,
                "position": "Midfielder",
                "age": 32,
                "birth_date": "29/03/1988",
                "birth_place": "Ciudad Lerdo",
                "birth_country": "Mexico",
                "nationality": "Mexico",
                "height": "177 cm",
                "weight": "67 kg",
                "injured": null,
                "rating": null,
                "team_id": 4299,
                "team_name": "Alianza",
                "league_id": 2979,
                "league": "Primera Division",
                "season": "2020-2021",
                "captain": 0,
                "shots": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "on": 0
                },
                "goals": {
                    "total": 5,
                    "conceded": 0,
                    "assists": 0,
                    "saves": 0
                },
                "passes": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "key": 0,
                    "accuracy": 0
                },
                "tackles": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "blocks": 0,
                    "interceptions": 0
                },
                "duels": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "won": 0
                },
                "dribbles": {
                    "attempts": 0,
                    "success": 0
                },
                "fouls": {
                    "drawn": 0,
                    "committed": 0
                },
                "cards": {
                    "yellow": 2,
                    "yellowred": 0,
                    "red": 0
                },
                "penalty": {
                    "won": 0,
                    "commited": 0,
                    "success": 0,
                    "missed": 0,
                    "saved": 0
                },
                "games": {
                    "appearences": 7,
                    "minutes_played": 260,
                    "lineups": 3
                },
                "substitutes": {
                    "in": 4,
                    "out": 3,
                    "bench": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

const allowedNames = ['goals', 'cards', 'games'];
const obj = json.api.players[0];


const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((accum, current) => {
  if(allowedNames.indexOf(current) !== -1) {
    accum.push(obj[current]);
  }
  return accum;
}, []);

console.log('result = ', result);
```